# Правильно понять полиморфизм

Tags: php, ооп, полиморфизм

Всем привет!
Помогите понять полиморфизм правильно. Так как примеров в Интернете много и все они отличаются друг от друга.

Как я его понимаю. Это когда свойство базового класса может использовать методы производных классов.

Часто встречаю в Интернет два примера полиморфизма

Пример 1.

```
class user {
    public $type = 'default_user';
    public function setName (){
    }
    public function Call (){
          return $this->setName();
    }
}
class admin extends user {
     public function setName (){
         return $this->type = "admin";
     }
}
class superUsers extends user {
    public function setName (){
        return $this->type = "superUser";
    }
}
$super = new superUsers;
$admin = new admin;
echo $super->call();
echo $admin->call();
```

Пример 2.

```
class user {
    public $type = 'default_user';
    public function setName (){
    }
}
class admin extends user {
     public function setName (){
         return $this->type = "admin";
     }
}
class superUsers extends user {
    public function setName (){
        return $this->type = "superUser";
    }
}
$super = new superUsers;
$admin = new admin;
echo $super->setName();
echo $admin->setName();
```

Так как я понял и в первом примере и во втором примере показан полиморфизм , а называется этот вид override.

Comment: " Это когда свойство базового класса может использовать методы производных классов." как то странно вы его понимаете. Базовый класс знать не знает о каких то свойствах классов-наследников, если они не объявлены в нем самом. в примерах речь идет о том, что производные классы-наследники наследюут функционал базовых, и могут переопределять методы (тут есть два варианта - скрытие/hide и перекрытие/override), а также расширять свой функционал.

Comment: тут у вас есть **1. Наследование**, когда в первом примере оба `admin` и `superUser` сохраняют родительский метод `Call`, **2. Инкапусляция** когда для доступа к членам класса используются методы (`setName`) с помощью которых можно регулировать доступ и управлять логикой изменения значений, и **3. полиморфизм** когда у вас в примерах базовый пустой `setName` переопределяется конечными разными реализациями в классах-наследниках.

Answer (score 10):

Стоит начать с того, что полиморфизм бывает разный.

В ООП полиморфизмом чаще всего называют способность классов с одинаковой спецификацией(интерфейсом) определять различную реализацию, что, в свою очередь, позволяет клиентскому коду абстрагироваться от этой самой реализации и работать с классом, исходя из его спецификации.

Например, ваш метод может ожидать получить на входе объект типа `UserInterface`, при этом не зная, с каким конкретным подтипом типа `UserInterface` он будет работать. Таким образом вы можете единообразно обрабатывать различные типы данных, полагаясь на то, что каждый входной параметр соответствует спецификации `UserInterface`.

При этом, в некоторых ООП языках используется т.н. "утиная типизация". Она же неявная типизация. Это когда клиентский код ожидает, что у используемого им объекта определен некоторый метод. Это позволяет использовать полиморфизм для обработки объектов, которые даже не обязательно входят в иерархию наследования.

Например, если я напишу функцию:

```
function ($object) {
    echo $object->setName();
}
```

Она сможет корректно работать как с вашими наследниками от `user`, так и с любым другим объектом, у которого можно вызвать метод `setName` без параметров, который возвращал бы строку. 
Например:

```
class DefinitelyNotAUser {

    public function setName()
    {
        return 'haduken!';
    }

}
```

Анонимная функция описаная выше сможет работать с экземплярами этого класса точно так же как и с вашими наследниками от `user`.

Это называется сигнатурным полиморфизмом. Такой подход широко распространен в Ruby, в PHP я бы не рекоммендовал его использовать.

Функция реализованная для произвольного типа данных также будет примером полиморфизма (параметрического). Например:

```
function handler($object, callable $action)
{
    return $action($object);
}

$result = handler(new admin(), function ($object) { echo $object->setName(); });
```

Стоит заметить, что полиморфизм не яляется чем-то свойственным исключительно объектно-ориентированной парадигме. Полиморфизм присутствует и в функциональной, и в процедурной парадигме. Параметрический полиморфизм функции описаной для произвольного типа данных - пример для ФП. Вызов конкретной реализации функции в зависимости от типов переданных параметров - пример полиморфизма для процедурного программирования.

Главное проявление полиморфизма - позднее связывание вызываемого кода с вызывающим, когда среда запуска умеет определять, какая именно вызывается реализация, исходя из контекста исполнения программы.

**Самое простое определение полиморфизма, которое вам сейчас необходимо запомнить, учитывая, что в тэгах к вопросу стоят PHP и ООП:** "Один интерфейс - много реализаций".

**Что неправильно в вашем текущем понимании:** вы зацикленны на отношениях базового и производных классов. Полиморфизм не об этом. Он о вызывающем (клиентском) коде и вызываемом, а также об их динамическом соответствии.